# Tomcat 7 TagLib and User Issues

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, taglib

First off... I am very new to Tomcat and all this, so please forgive me if any of this is considered "basic"

I am running Tomcat 7 on my Mac (OS X 10.7.5).  I have installed and currently running Tomcat, for the most part, correctly.

I need to include a line at the beginning to define my taglib and am using this code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

When I run the page, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [47] in the generated java file: [/Users/me/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/popup/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

I have no idea what is going on, or why this would even flag an error.

===========================

The second issue I am having is to access the manager app.  I have followed all instruction on how to modify the tomcat-user.xml to add a new user and assign them the role of "manager-gui", but it's just not recognizing the user-list.

I have tried using all of the pre-defined user/passwords in the tomcat-users.xml and none of them work.  At least I would think that if it was working properly, there would be an error message "This account does not have sufficient priviliges to access the manager app" or something... but it just keeps on kicking me back to the login screen.

Is there a way I can use Mac's Terminal to list the known users? or how can I at least check the tomcat-users.xml is being referenced correctly.

Comment: Regarding the exception, ensure you are not bundling with your application (i.e. in WEB-INF/LIB), any JARs that are provided by Tomcat e.g. jsp-api-x.jar or servlet-api-x.jar - especially the former in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncomment the user-list at the file *tomcat-user.xml* and then restart the server.

Comment: well now I feel like a complete idiot... I didn't even see the comment tags.  thank you.. that solves that issue.

Comment: I'm glad I helped, please vote up the answer.

Comment: That was only half my issue.

Comment: You don't need to check my answer as correct, just vote up because it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You must place your custom tag libraries into the directory / TOMCAT_HOME / lib